# How to deal with a large API for a KoTH

Tags: discussion, king-of-the-hill

My upcoming KoTH, [Fellowship](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9188/20198), has a *really* large API.

Fundamentally, there are 5 classes the player needs to work with:

- [Player](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/blob/master/src/fellowship/Player.java) is the class they need to implement (6 functions)
- [ReadonlyCharacter](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/blob/master/src/fellowship/characters/ReadonlyCharacter.java) is the class for each of the characters they control (25 functions)
- [ReadonlyAbility](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/blob/master/src/fellowship/abilities/ReadonlyCharacterAbility.java) is the class for abilities characters can have (4 functions)
- [ReadonlyAction](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/blob/master/src/fellowship/actions/ReadonlyAction.java) is the class for actions characters can have (7 functions)
- [ReadonlyTeam](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/blob/master/src/fellowship/teams/ReadonlyTeam.java)/[EnemyTeam](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/Fellowship/blob/master/src/fellowship/teams/EnemyTeam.java) are classes for the teams the characters are on. (4 functions)

Some of these are less important (teams and abilities), but if my post is going to be self-contained, I would theoretically need to describe all of the functions I've listed above.

I've got a couple of options here:

1. Only describe the critical parts in my post.  Answer any questions in comments/chat.
2. Describe everything.  This would lead to a post with lots of information unimportant to most readers (and a *really* long post)
3. Something else?

What should I do in my situation?

Comment: Hi Nathan  - I know this is an old question but how did this work out in the end? Were there any issues with working with an over-large interface?

Comment: I ended up describing the overall concepts, and just had a big code dump listing all of the individual functions: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99744/battle-of-the-fellowships-koth

Comment: Oh wow! You weren’t joking about that being a big API. I think I’d forgotten just how long CGC questions get.

Answer (score 3):

### Describe only the information about the public API that readers need to know

You don't have to go into detail about how every part of the public API is implemented - just a rough overview of the different classes and methods, and their uses.

For example, if you have a method that looks like this:

```
public UsefulInformation getInformation() {
    // 100 lines of code
}
```

It's fine to not include the `// 100 lines of code`, and just include the method signature and a brief comment describing the method:

```
// returns a UsefulInformation object containing the current game state
public UsefulInformation getInformation();
```

If anyone wants full implementation details, they can look at the full source code that you have hosted in a public location (like a public GitHub repository), via the link you include in the challenge body.

Comment: "Need to know" is a bit unclear?  There are lots of "informational" functions that readers who want to write a decently competitive bot will need to know.  On the flipside, I can only explain the minimum number of functions that readers need to know to understand the post.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Is that better?

Comment: To be clear, you are indicating that I should list all 46 public methods with a short description?  If that's your intention, then, yes its clear :)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Ideally, yes. If you run into post length issues, you may consider linking to a GitHub Gist or a README file in the repository for the explanations. Bonus points if you compress the explanations and include the base64-encoded compressed file.